# Ruby debugger: weird sort of caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-debug

I'm using Ruby debugger gem in my RoR project. Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2

Debugger works fine by a sort of weird file caching occurs.

I mean:

First example

```
[4, 13] in /.../app/controllers/fork_controller.rb
   4    def index
   5  
   6        debugger
   7        a = "hello"
   8  
=> 9        puts "#{a}"
   10  
   11    end
   12  
   13    def requesting    
(rdb:4) eval a
"hello"
(rdb:4) continue
```

Then I change var "a" to "**hello2**"

```
def index

    debugger
    a = "hello2"

    puts "#{a}"

  end
```

this is the result:

```
[4, 13] in /.../app/controllers/fork_controller.rb
   4    def index
   5  
   6        debugger
   7        a = "hello"
   8  
=> 9        puts "#{a}"
   10  
   11    end
   12  
   13    def requesting    
(rdb:4) eval a
"hello2"
(rdb:4) continue
```

So ... the variable evaluation is correct "hello2" instead of "hello" but ... the "breakpoint view" show the first variable content "hello".

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ur using `irb` or `ruby file.rb`

Comment: It's the console output of Rails

Comment: Restart the server and try again. Don't hit "enter" key.

Comment: Restart the server. If you edit a ruby file like this, while the process is already running, it's possible you may encounter some "cacheing" issue. In theory, the file should have autoloaded the changes, but you're using ancient ruby/rails versions so I wouldn't presume anything about their precise behaviour.

Comment: (Is there a good reason why you're using such old ruby/rails versions?)

Comment: try `reload!` to reload the code in console

Comment: @Tom thanks for your answer. It's a legacy project and I can't update anything.